# Large file size download

Tags: file-transfer, large-data, large-files, bittorrent

I am looking into making a system for work where you can download huge video files, (Im talking 4k full length videos which have a file size of sometimes 500GB) and I'm looking into the best way of doing this.

Would it simply need a file manager to split the download? or could I use bittorrent?

any suggestions?

Comment: When you say make, do you mean you are going to code something?

Where are the files to be stored, is it something like Amazon s3? I work for a company that shifts large video files around and there are a number of solutions already out there, some very expensive, let us know more.

Answer (score 0):

Bittorrent can be used to to 1:1 transfers and has the benefit of hash-verifying the contents and being able to resume the transfer when it has been interrupted. But that can also achieved with other tools such as rsync.

Bittorrent's strength is making the transfer between many nodes scalable and being able to work in a decentralized manner.